# Splash screen and statusbar on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, splash-screen, statusbar

My app for Windows Phone 7 does not hide the statusbar, so i don't want  the splashscreen to cover the status bar. If i try to use a shorter image in the splashscreen, it gets anchored to the top of the screen and repeat at the bottom.
Is there a way to show the status bar and a shorter image or a png with transparency image?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to change the size of the splash screen. However, if you want a custom splash screen experience, you could remove the default splash screen image from your project and load your first page with your custom splash experience. Once you have completed your application load tasks, you can then hide the "splash" screen to reveal the standard UI. You may find this [blog post](http://wp7trenches.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/splash/) useful/helpful.

Comment: Yep. The thing to watch out for in a custom splash XAML page is managing the page backstack. Make sure your app exits from the first actual page on hitting the Back button.

Comment: Thank you very much for the precious link!